# i have data like 142456,Thakur Vinay,First.how to get name using substring in mysql?

Tags: mysql

142456, Vinay Singh, First

i want to get the name from the above data usingsubstringfunction in mysql

please can anyone suggest about this

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern is same for all the strings then the following should do the trick

```
mysql> select substring_index( substring_index('142456, Vinay Singh, First',',',2),',',-1);
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| substring_index( substring_index('142456, Vinay Singh, First',',',2),',',-1) |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  Vinay Singh                                                                 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```